# Change element to an iFrame onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I created this:

https://codepen.io/Blvcksquid/pen/yLpdBoO

Now I want a js function thats assigned to the onclick button function "schach()".
The function should change the "box" element on click to an iframe element with the url "schach.coach".

I tried to write the function on my own, but the variable doesnt work:

```
function schach() {
  let content = "  <iframe  class="box2" src="https://schach.coach" style="border:3px #black solid"; name="myiFrame" scrolling="yes" frameborder='1' marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="450px" width="240px" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
      document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "content"
     }
```

I am sure something's wrong with my content variable or am I even using the wrong function?
Please help, I am a beginner and hungry to learn.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are assigning a string to the box instead of the actual content of the variable. Try this line instead:

```
document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = content;
```

Notice that I have removed the double quotes from the word "content"

Comment: This isn´t working: `function schach() {
  let content = "  <iframe  class="box2" src="https://schach.coach" style="border:3px #black solid"; name="myiFrame" scrolling="yes" frameborder='1' marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="450px" width="240px" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
      document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = content
     }`